# express-rate-limit blocks request by my client app IP and not by users IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, rate-limiting

I have the following problem. I have two apps deployed on DigitalOcean, `API` (using Nodejs and express) and `CLIENT` (create-react-app).
I want to add an api call rate limiter. I've tried using `express-rate-limiter` but, if I undertand correctly, it blocks the request taking the `CLIENT` app IP, so when it reaches the max api calls allowed, `express-rate-limiter` blocks all the requests. Here my rate limiter middleware

```js
import rateLimit from "express-rate-limit";

const apiCallRateLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 1,
  message: "You have reached maximum retries. Please try again later",
  statusCode: 429,
  headers: true,
});

app.use(apiCallRateLimiter);
app.use("/", router);
```

I've tried this [express-rate-limit blocking requests from all users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67630477/18901890), but it didn't work. The middlewares look like this

```js
import rateLimit from "express-rate-limit";
import { mw } from "request-ip";

const apiCallRateLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 1,
  message: "You have reached maximum retries. Please try again later",
  statusCode: 429,
  headers: true,
  keyGenerator: (req, res) => req.clientIp
});

app.use(mw());
app.use(apiCallRateLimiter);
app.use("/", router);
```

How can I limit the api calls taking the user IP and not my `CLIENT` app IP? Thanks in advance

Comment: #1 Is your client a web csr (react, angular, vue) or ssr? #2 Is the web using a loadbalancer like nginx ? #3 Do  you want to protect the web or the api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the arrow function at `keyGenerator` to an anonymous function and now it's working

```js
const apiCallRateLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 1,
  message: "You have reached maximum retries. Please try again later",
  statusCode: 429,
  headers: true,
  keyGenerator(req) {
    return req.clientIp;
  },
});
```